# How to include prestashop inside a website?

Tags: php, iframe, smarty, prestashop

I have a website (which was in html and I converted it to php) and one of the pages is the shopping page which I used prestashop. I have used iframe code to show the prestashop inside my website. How can I include prestashop inside my php website without using iframe?

I have tried  php include() but it doesn't work! 
I have tried some smarty codes {include_php} and it didn't work either.

is there any way to do that? or am I forced to use iframe?

Comment: I don't think it can be done in a easy way (ie: what about urls?). Also, both are really bad ideas. Why don't you just put the shop in a /shop folder and replicate the layout of the main site if it really has to look alike? or you can use prestashop as the main site and add all the content pages there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end I have changed they way I was thinking! Instead of including the prestashop inside the html website with iFrame, I have converted the html pages to php, and included the php header and footer of my website inside the prestashop using iFrame.

It was very difficult because of many changes that I had to do on prestashop codes, images, css, and literally redesigning the entire website to fit with the new codes and look exactly the same, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is an iFrame for sure.

You can't include it directly, easily because it sets up sessions, handle redirection etc which would fail.

My advice would be to create a theme that matched your website, then from within your Prestashop theme, include your header and footer code.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to setup Prestashop in a folder under the root of your current PHP website. Many examples are out there : see http://www.webbax.ch/shop or http://www.magavenue.com/boutique/accueil.
I hope it helps!